# Clojure: cons (seq) vs. conj (list)

Tags: collections, clojure, sequence

I know that `cons` returns a seq and `conj` returns a collection.  I also know that `conj` "adds" the item to the optimal end of the collection, and `cons` always "adds" the item to the front.  This example illustrates both of these points:

```
user=> (conj [1 2 3] 4) ; returns a collection
[1 2 3 4]
user=> (cons 4 [1 2 3]) ; returns a seq
(4 1 2 3)
```

For vectors, maps, and sets these differences make sense to me.  However, for lists they seem identical.

```
user=> (conj (list 3 2 1) 4) ; returns a list
(4 3 2 1)
user=> (cons 4 (list 3 2 1)) ; returns a seq
(4 3 2 1)
```

Are there any examples using lists where `conj` vs. `cons` exhibit different behaviors, or are they truly interchangeable?  Phrased differently, is there an example where a list and a seq cannot be used equivalently?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

One difference is that `conj` accepts any number of arguments to insert into a collection, while `cons` takes just one:

```
(conj '(1 2 3) 4 5 6)
; => (6 5 4 1 2 3)

(cons 4 5 6 '(1 2 3))
; => IllegalArgumentException due to wrong arity
```

Another difference is in the class of the return value:

```
(class (conj '(1 2 3) 4))
; => clojure.lang.PersistentList

(class (cons 4 '(1 2 3))
; => clojure.lang.Cons
```

Note that these are not really interchangeable; in particular, `clojure.lang.Cons` does not implement `clojure.lang.Counted`, so a `count` on it is no longer a constant time operation (in this case it would probably reduce to 1 + 3 -- the 1 comes from linear traversal over the first element, the 3 comes from `(next (cons 4 '(1 2 3))` being a `PersistentList` and thus `Counted`).

The intention behind the names is, I believe, that `cons` means to cons(truct a seq)<sup>1</sup>, whereas `conj` means to conj(oin an item onto a collection). The `seq` being constructed by `cons` starts with the element passed as its first argument and has as its `next` / `rest` part the thing resulting from the application of `seq` to the second argument; as displayed above, the whole thing is of class `clojure.lang.Cons`. In contrast, `conj` always returns a collection of roughly the same type as the collection passed to it. (Roughly, because a `PersistentArrayMap` will be turned into a `PersistentHashMap` as soon as it grows beyond 9 entries.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Traditionally, in the Lisp world, `cons` cons(tructs a pair), so Clojure departs from the Lisp tradition in having its `cons` function construct a seq which doesn't have a traditional `cdr`. The generalised usage of `cons` to mean "construct a record of some type or other to hold a number of values together" is currently ubiquitous in the study of programming languages and their implementation; that's what's meant when "avoiding consing" is mentioned.

Comment: What a fantastic writeup! I was unaware that there was a Cons type. Well done!

Comment: Incidentally, as a special case, `(cons foo nil)` returns a singleton `PersistentList` (and likewise for `conj`).

Comment: Another superb explanation. You truly are a clojure jedi!

Comment: In my experience, treating lists as lists and not as seqs ias important when performance matters.

Answer (score 12):

My understanding is that what you say is true: conj on a list is equivalent to cons on a list.

You can think of conj as being an "insert somewhere" operation, and cons as being an "insert at the head" operation. On a list, it is most logical to insert at the head, so conj and cons are equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 9):

Another difference is that because `conj` takes a sequence as the first argument, it plays nicely with `alter` when updating a `ref` to some sequence:

```
(dosync (alter a-sequence-ref conj an-item))
```

This basically does `(conj a-sequence-ref an-item)` in a thread-safe manner. This wouldn't work with `cons`. See the chapter on Concurrency in [Programming Clojure](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure) by Stu Halloway for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Another difference is the behavior of list?

```
(list? (conj () 1)) ;=> true
(list? (cons 1 ())) ; => false
```

Comment: cons always returns a sequence which conj returns the same type of the one provided

Answer (score -1):

There are [dedicated functions in the Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#adding-values-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-sequence) to add append or prepend values to any sequential collection:

```
(append [1 2] 3  )   ;=> [1 2 3  ]
(append [1 2] 3 4)   ;=> [1 2 3 4]

(prepend   3 [2 1])  ;=> [  3 2 1]
(prepend 4 3 [2 1])  ;=> [4 3 2 1]
```