# common lisp cons creates a list from two symbols, clojure cons requires a seq to cons onto?

Tags: clojure, lisp, common-lisp, sequence, cons

(Disclaimer - I'm aware of the significance of Seqs in Clojure)

In common lisp the cons function can be used to combine two symbols into a list:

```
(def s 'x)
(def l 'y)
(cons s l)
```

In clojure - you can only cons onto a sequence - cons hasn't been extended to work with two symbols. So you have to write:

```
(def s 'x)
(def l 'y)
(cons s '(l))
```

Is there a higher level pattern in Clojure that explains this difference between Common LISP and Clojure?

Comment: I've been programming in Clojure a bit and wasn't even aware of this! If what you claim is correct, this is a good question :)

Comment: Note that it's normally better to use `conj` than `cons`. For more details, see my answer to this question (and the comment by cgrand): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008411/clojure-seq-cons-vs-list-conj (In fact, that answer also explains the function of `cons` in Clojure as contrasted to the traditional Lisp `cons` to a certain degree.)

Comment: Your first example is not a list, it's a pair. A pair (a . b) is different from a list of two elements (a b), which happens to be the pair (a . (b . nil))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Clojure, unlike traditional Lisps, lists are not the primary data structures. The data structures can implement the [ISeq](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java) interface - which is another view of the data structure it's given - allowing the same functions to access elements in each. (Lists already implement this. `seq?` checks whether something implements [ISeq](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java).`(seq? '(1 2)), (seq? [1 2]))` Clojure simply acts differently (with good reason), in that when `cons` is used, a sequence (it's actually of type `clojure.lang.Cons`) constructed of `a` and `(seq b)` is returned. (`a` being arg 1 and `b` arg 2) Obviously, symbols don't and can't implement [ISeq](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java).

[Clojure.org/sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences)

[Sequences screencast/talk by Rich Hickey](http://clojure.blip.tv/file/734409/) However, note that `rest` has changed, and it's previous behaviour is now in `next`, and that `lazy-cons` has been replaced by `lazy-seq` and `cons`.

[clojure.lang.RT](http://github.com/hiredman/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java)

Answer (score 6):

In Common Lisp CONS creates a so-called CONS cell, which is similar to a record with two slots: the 'car' and the 'cdr'.

You can put ANYTHING into those two slots of a cons cell.

Cons cells are used to build lists. But one can create all kinds of data structures with cons cells: trees, graphs, various types of specialized lists, ...

The implementations of Lisp are highly optimized to provide very efficient cons cells.

Answer (score 3):

A Lisp list is just a common way of using cons cells (see [Rainer's description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222789/common-lisp-cons-creates-a-list-from-two-symbols-clojure-cons-requires-a-seq-to/3222916#3222916)).  Clojure is best seen as not having cons cells (although something similar might hide under the hood).  The Clojure `cons` is a misnomer, it should actually just be named `prepend`.

Answer (score 3):

In Clojure the use of a two-element vector is preferred: `[:a :b]`. Under the hood such small vectors are implemented as Java arrays and are extremely simple and fast.

A short hand for `(cons :a '(:b))` (or `(cons :a (cons :b nil))`) is `list`: `(list :a :b)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
> (cons 'a 'b)
```

in common lisp you dont get a list but a dotted pair: `(a . b)`, whereas the result of

```
> (cons 'a (cons 'b nil))
```

is the dotted pair `(a . ( b . nil))`.

In the first list the `cdr()` of that is not a list, since it is here `b` and not `nil`, making it an improper list. Proper lists must be terminated by `nil`. Therefore higher order functions like `mapcar()` and friends won't work, but we save a cons-cell. I guess the designers of Clojure removed this feature because of the confusion it could cause.

Comment: It should be noted that `(a . (b . nil))` _is_ a Lisp list, commonly noted as `(a b)`.