# Collection of pairs in Clojure using cons

Tags: java, clojure

I was writing a Sieve-type function in Clojure based on Sieve of Eratosthenes.....and came across an error with lists of pairs: ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.remainder (Numbers.java:171)

---

```
(defn mark-true [n]
  (cons n '(true)))

(defn unmarked? [ns]
  (not (list? ns)))

(defn divides? [m n]
  (if (= (mod n m) 0)
      true
      false ))

(defn mark-divisors [n ns]
  (cond 
      (empty? ns) '()
      (and (unmarked? (first ns)) (divides? n (first ns))) 
           (cons (cons (first ns) '(false)) (mark-divisors n (rest ns)))
      :else (cons (first ns) (mark-divisors n (rest ns)))))

(defn eratosthenes [ns]
  (cond 
      (empty? ns) '()
      (unmarked? (first ns))
           (cons (mark-true (first ns)) 
                 (eratosthenes (mark-divisors (first ns) (rest ns))))
      :else (cons (first ns) (eratosthenes (rest ns)))))
```

---

```
;(eratosthenes (list 2 3 4 5 6))
;=> ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.lang.Number&nbsp; clojure.lang.Numbers.remainder (Numbers.java:171)
```

However, changing the marking style, giving up on cons and using conj or vector pairs instead, both solved the error.

Still I am looking for a good explanation of the error....

Comment: You can't expect an answer if you don't post all the relevant code. There is no remainder call in there... clearly `mark-divisors` is missing.

Comment: you are right - thaks

Comment: at some point divides? function receive 3 and (4 false) args. Second arg can't be cast to number

Comment: why would using a different making like (defn mark-true [n]
  (conj '(true) n)) make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `list?` check fails on a sequence built with `cons` as demonstrated below:

```
(list? (conj () 1)) ;=> true
(list? (cons 1 ())) ; => false
```

You could switch your call to `list?` to a call to `seq?` and it should work.

For details on why this is so I recommend reading this answer: [Clojure: cons(seq) vs. conj(list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008411/clojure-seq-cons-vs-list-conj/3009747#3009747)

Comment: Great. Thanks for solution. Funny list? is not discussed in reading ref. Your example should be an included there and http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/list_q

Comment: I think is a mistake in design to have (list? (cons 1 ())) ; => false

Comment: @FredAKA, you need to to take into account that there is a distinction between a list and a seq in Clojure.

Comment: surely, dont need to "call" it a list and conflict with the well understood abstraction of that goes back to the first lisps built using cons